# Facing Failed to load extension from <path>..loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator issue for ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Facing Failed to load extension from ..loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator issue for ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 even after using below set of code in Selenium Webdriver.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
Webdriver d=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Note : Working fine for ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 when above code is used. Attached screen shot for reference.

Requesting to pls help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owwRy.png)